# Get updated fields with xml and only update those with prepared MySQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm currently on something.
I get XML Files with fields that are changed to previous versions. Say i got:

```
ID | Column A | Column B
1  | Foo      | Bar
```

And now the User changes Foo to Bar, I get a XML File with "column A is updated to Bar". I don't see the value of Column B.

How can I dynamically update those new values in mysql?

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"UPDATE table SET **DYNAMIC** WHERE idbenutzer = ? AND token = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, '**DYNAMIC**', **DYNAMIC**);
```

Comment: have you parsed the xml already?

Comment: you can't use placeholders for sql identifiers. placeholders are for VALUES only. therefore you'll have to manually build your string, e.g. `"update $table set " . implode(',', $fields) . ' etc...`, and then dynamically bind values as well.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes the xml is already parsed into an simplexmlobject

Comment: @MarcB: but how is this a prepared statement?

Comment: because you can still use placeholders for the VALUES. you just can't do it for field names. once you've built your sql string, it can still be prepared and placeholders for the values can get bound.